# Any way to embed maps list view in HTML like what is seen on normal Google Maps?

Tags: html, google-maps, maps

I'm using the google maps API and am planning on embedding it in a website. I've been able to embed an interactive map using an http request, but I have to click on each individual point of interest to see a little bit of info on the place without images. Just the name, address, and rating. I'd like to be able to recreate the results bar that Google Maps has.

Is this possible with any of the APIs in the maps suite?

Thanks. Here's a pic of what I'm talking about.

[image: this is what I'm trying to recreate]

The map and markers are what is embeded alone, but as of now I don't think there's a way to get the bar on the left to appear. I'm assuming there's no way.

Answer (score 0):

Like this sir ?

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d7021.738121507687!2d-83.73387091940336!3d42.272605630582206!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x883cae45cc20c635%3A0xab7fb96b1315bd3b!2sThe%20Garage%20Bar!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1580184370674!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Comment: This results in the same thing. [Heres](https://i.imgur.com/x9YqmSq.png) what it looks like when I add this.